# POST form data containing spaces with Python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm probably overlooking something spectacularly obvious, but I can't find why the following is happening.

I'm trying to POST a search query to http://www.arcade-museum.com using the requests lib and whenever the query contains spaces, the resulting page contains no results. Compare the result of these snippets:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.arcade-museum.com/results.php"
payload = {'type': 'Videogame', 'q': '1942'}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
with open("search_results.html", mode="wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

and

```
import requests
url = "http://www.arcade-museum.com/results.php"
payload = {'type': 'Videogame', 'q': 'Wonder Boy'}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
with open("search_results.html", mode="wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

If you try the same query on the website, the latter will result in a list of about 10 games. The same happens when posting the form data using [the Postman REST client Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en):

[image: Postman does it right]

Again, it's probably something very obvious I'm overlooking, but I can't find what's causing this issue.

Comment: Could always try `'Wonder%20Boy'` or `'Wonder+Boy'`.

Comment: It seems like the search engine depends on case. Try `payload = {'type': 'Videogame', 'q': 'wonder boy'}`. (lowercase)

Comment: It is indeed! Postman doesn't show any results either when searching with "Wonder Boy". I got trapped into thinking the spaces were the culprit. Thanks!